# Is there a way to pull up your own Q/A statistics?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I'm curious how I might access some statistics for one of my SE site profiles. I'm curious as to what percentage of my answers have been accepted, and I'm sure I'll find some other bits of data interesting.

How can I access such statistics? (Note: I found another question where the answerer pointed to data.stackexchange.com as a place to find "user statistics", but the main site I'm interested in, Philosophy.SE, doesn't appear on that site)

Comment: data.SE does not include Beta sites yet, which explains why Photography is not included.

Comment: @psubsee2003: You mean Philosophy. Photo.SE graduated. In fact, it graduated so much that their theme is slightly configurable by the community. :)

Comment: @Manishearth opps... that is indeed what I meant.  That's what I get for multitasking and actually working while checking in at lunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the beta sites are now also in SEDE [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/philosophy/query/208337/how-is-my-answer-vs-accepted-rate?uid=2297) answers your question.

```
-- uid: User id from the url " for example 2297 on Philosophy"
declare @uid integer = ##uid## -- 2297

select count(a.id) as [total answers]
     , sum(case when q.id is not null then 1 else 0 end ) as [accepted]
     , (100 * sum(case when q.id is not null then 1 else 0 end )) / count(a.id)  as [rate]
from posts a
left outer join posts q on q.acceptedanswerid = a.id
where a.posttypeid = 2 -- Answer
and a.owneruserid = @uid
```

At the moment of posting the outcome for your account is:

```
total answers accepted rate 
------------- -------- ---- 
50            25       50
```

Comment: @3ventic: evidently, and rounded down. [My rate is 28 on CV](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/208337/how-is-my-answer-vs-accepted-rate?uid=32036), but 62/216=.287

Comment: @NickStauner yeah there was an issue with it that I pointed out in chat.